# Laravel Show Table Relation Only if Has Value

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 tables Category & Transaction

in my model Category :

```
  public function transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

in my model Transaction :

```
  public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Architecture of my Transactions table :

```
id | category_id | qty
```

Architecture of my Categories table :

```
id | name
```

Now , how to display in view which i want to display only categories that have quantity(qty) value in Transactions table , i'm may have a lot of category in categories table , but not all categories has quantity in transactions table .

Normal in controller to pass view

```
  public function getChart1()
{
    $kato = Category::all();

    return view('a.chart1',compact('kato'));
}
```

So in view :

```
@foreach($kato as $kat)
{{$kat->name}} 
{{$kat->transaction->sum('qty')}}
@endforeach
```

By normal, but how to make sure the foreach , is not looping the categories with empty quantity?

Thank you

note : if my question were stupid enough, forgive me , i already spend 1 week to study about this .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach($kato as $kat)
@if($kat->transaction->count() > 0)
{{$kat->name}} 
{{$kat->transaction->sum('qty')}}
@endif
@endforeach
```